# RegEx for comparison of two strings with special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string-comparison

I am using .Equals() method to check equality of my strings. I have over a dozen different strings
and it is working fine for all the strings but I got stuck with Phone number and Address.

> I have  stringA as (111)-22-3333 and stringB as 111223333.

Is it possible to make use of regex to make this comparison result in true while still doing .Equals(). I am new to RegEx.

I tried using replaceAll before doing .Equals but I got "String does not contain a definition for replaceAll....." error.

Comment: As the error is telling you, no such method exists.  C# is not Java.  Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have correctly explained you can make use of a combination of RegEx and String comparison (Equals) here. First I would remove every non-numeric character from the stringA (using RegEx) and afterwards compare the two strings. In code it would look like this:

```
stringA = "(111)-22-3333";
stringB = "11122333";

if(Regex.Replace(stringA, "[^0-9]", "").Equals(stringB)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Match found!");
}else {
   Console.WriteLine("Try again...");
}
```

This should work fine for your solution, I verified it to work on my local machine. Anyways I'm not sure how this would perform for huge strings.